"Of every tribe a thousand" - serving G-d being of one heart
In parshas Matos (Bamidbar 31:3-4), we read:

"And Moshe spoke to the people, saying, Arm from yourselves men for the army, and let them go against Midyan and avenge the L-rd on Midyan. Of every tribe a thousand, throughout all the tribes of Yisroel, shall you send to the war".

The Baal HaTurim (ad loc.) observes that this posuk begins with an "alef" and ends with an "alef".

אֶ֚לֶף לַמַּטֶּ֔ה אֶ֖לֶף לַמַּטֶּ֑ה - תִּשְׁלְח֖וּ לַצָּבָֽא

The Baal HaTurim explains that this means that B'nei Yisroel were all of one heart to their Father in Heaven.

One thousand from each tribe. The verse begins with an aleph and ends with an aleph, which teaches that they were all of one heart to their Father in Heaven.

What exactly does this mean? Are there explanations on what this Baal HaTurim means and how this is important when fighting Hashem's wars?

Maybe related to the idea in Heichaltzu that this was a war of divine unity against the spirit of division and hatred channeled by Midian.

@shmosel which chapter because that is interesting

Aleph means one. Start with Aleph and ends with Apeph hints at everything enclosed aligning with one. One what, one leg, one arm? No, one heart. One heart of what? Of their worship to Hashem. Rather simple induction.

The verse is talking about new generation who did not stand at mt. Sinai. One could think that Baal haTurim hints that the new generation achieved unity for the war comparable to the one their fathers had when receiving the Torah, as Rashi to Exodus 19:2 quotes Mekhilta d'Rabbi Yishmael 19:2:10, כאיש אחד בלב אחד - as one man with one heart. However, the Rashi's comment states, that only at Sinai the encampment of Bnei Yisrael had such kind of unity. In other words the Jewish people were united in their desire to serve Hashem, be a holly nation, which brought their hearts and minds in unison. A similar expression is used when describing the approaching of the pharaoh's army towards bnei Yisrael, see Rashi to Exodus 14:10 quoting Mekhilta d'Rabbi Yishmael 14:10:3: בלב אחד כאיש אחד - with one heart like one man - in reverse order vs. Exodus 19:2. In other words the unity of a heart was built by the thought of revenge against the enemy. Egyptians were seeking revenge against Israelies, and Israelies were seeking revenge against Midianites and in both cases the idea united the people.
The reason why unity when waging war is important is discussed in mishna Sota 8:5 among other places. Any breach of the front line due to any lack of unity can lead to exceedingly large losses. In fact all mishnayot in perek 8 of Sota add good points on the issue of unity.

Thanks. But why is achdus important when waging wars?

@Shmuel added a small but significant point in the last paragraph. There are probably wordier and better answers.
